# HTML/CSS - Border length

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a page with 4 sections containing lists of links.  I've set the left and right border on each section to `1px solid black`.

The issue is these borders only extend to the length of my content.  I haven't been able to find a way to have them extend the full length of the page.  The related topics I've been finding deal with bottom-borders.

Sorry for the long code but I'm not sure how to really shorten it much and still show what is needed:

```css
div.container {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(0, 56, 0);
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

a:link {
  color: rgb(0, 68, 255);
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: aqua;
}

a:visited {
  color: rgb(27, 164, 255);
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

header.jira {
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  color: goldenrod;
  font-size: 200%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  color: black;
  list-style-type: disc;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

section.wiki {
  float: left;
  max-width: 220px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

section.monitoring {
  float: left;
  max-width: 220px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

section.adminui {
  float: left;
  max-width: 220px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

section.other {
  float: left;
  max-width: 220px;
  height: to-bottom;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container">

    <header class="jira">
      <h1 style="color: white">Useful Links</h1>
    </header>

    <section class="wiki">
      <h2>Wiki</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <section class="monitoring">
      <h2>Monitoring</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <section class="adminui">
      <h2>AdminUI</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <section class="other">
      <h2>Other</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <footer>footer</footer>

  </div>

</body>
```

The borders for the `monitoring` and `adminui` sections extend all the way down but the `wiki` and `other` sections do not causing the lines to not be full the entire length of the page.  Granted I know I can just remove the borders from `wiki` right and `other` left and it will look okay but I would like it to be proper in case I have to add more links in the future.

---

How can I make the left and right borders for my sections extend the full length of the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use flex for the layout instead of floating and the element will all have the same height and thus all the border will continu to the end:

```css
div.container {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(0, 56, 0);
  max-width: 900px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

a:link {
  color: rgb(0, 68, 255);
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: aqua;
}

a:visited {
  color: rgb(27, 164, 255);
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

header.jira {
  padding: 1em;
  width:100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
}

h2 {
  color: goldenrod;
  font-size: 200%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  color: black;
  list-style-type: disc;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

section.wiki {
  flex:1;
  max-width: 220px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

section.monitoring {
  flex:1;
  max-width: 220px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

section.adminui {
  flex:1;
  max-width: 220px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

section.other {
  flex:1;
  max-width: 220px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container">

    <header class="jira">
      <h1 style="color: white">Useful Links</h1>
    </header>

    <section class="wiki">
      <h2>Wiki</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <section class="monitoring">
      <h2>Monitoring</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <section class="adminui">
      <h2>AdminUI</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <section class="other">
      <h2>Other</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Some Page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <footer>footer</footer>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

If you define your height for each section (whatever the longest section(s) is/are, and make all the sections that height then the border should match.

So in each css section.* you need to define height.

height: #px;

replace the # with the actual height of the longest section(s) and the short areas will use the defined height with the border. You will have to fiddle around with it to get the perfect number of pixels but then you that number for all heights.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what if the content is dynamic and always change ? what about responsive also. It's not a good idea to specify a fixed height based on the content we have as this will never be a generic solution and we have to manually calculate/adjust the height each time we change the content